# Добавленные элементы в список не удаляются

Tags: javascript, jquery

Элементы, которые изначально были добавлены в список, удаляются без проблем. Но элементы, которые после выбора (клик по нужной панели), идут в список, и при клике у них на Х не удаляются.

Почему это происходит и как можно это исправить?

```js
$("#tableList .btn-add").click(function() {
  var icon = $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa fa-plus").addClass("fa fa-check").css("color", "#008000");
  var elemNum = $(this).parent().siblings(".list-link").find(".header-item p").text();
  var li = $("#codesList").append("<li>" + "<span>" + elemNum + "</span>" + "<span class='btn-list-close'>&#10006;</span>" + "</li>");
});
$("#codesList li .btn-list-close").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-list" id="tableList">
  <div class="list-item">
    <a href="#" class="list-link">
      <div class="header-item">
        <p>001</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="footer-item">
      <span class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-item">
    <a href="#" class="list-link">
      <div class="header-item">
        <p>002</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="footer-item">
      <span class="btn-add"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На созданные элементы нужны использовать делегирования события

```
$(document).on('click', "#codesList li .btn-list-close", function() {
  $(this).parent().remove();
});
```